# Laravel Filament FileUpload not working with filled()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I use Laravel Filament in my project. When I create an input as follows:

```
TextInput::make("title")->filled()
```

This shows a notification when I try to submit with an empty title field.

But same filled() function doesn't work with FileUpload. When I submit form without image, form proceeds without a notification. What am I missing?

```
FileUpload::make('image')
                ->columnSpan('full') 
                ->filled()
                ->disk('public')
                ->directory('gallery')
                ->visibility('public')
                ->imageResizeMode('force')
                ->imageCropAspectRatio('8:5')
                ->imageResizeTargetWidth('800')
                ->imageResizeTargetHeight('500')
                ->image()
                ->imageEditor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `nullable` method, It gives you the same popup as `filled`

But it adds the required CSS class after the label.

```php
FileUpload::make('image')
    ->columnSpan('full')
    // replace filled with nullable
    ->nullable(false)
    ->disk('public')
    ->directory('gallery')
    ->visibility('public')
    ->imageResizeMode('force')
    ->imageCropAspectRatio('8:5')
    ->imageResizeTargetWidth('800')
    ->imageResizeTargetHeight('500')
    ->image()
    ->imageEditor(),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate a `FileUpload` field to ensure that it contains a file, you can use the required() validation rule

```
FileUpload::make('image')
    ->columnSpan('full')
    ->required()
    ->disk('public')
    // the rest of your code
    ;
```

or a custom validation rule named `ImageRequired`.